# application in docker with a remote database?

Tags: docker

I am having the following question. I have an application (java) that I just moved into docker.

This application has a database remote (means is not localhost), that database cannot get into a docker, the application itself will not run migrations (like when you start it from a freshly created database).

So my question is, how do you declare it at your docker-compose file? or you dont declare it at all?

So far I made it like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
 my-java-app:
    image: localimage:1.0
    environment:
      SOME_VAR: some-vaoue
      DB_URL: my-db-url
```

so my dockercompose sends the variables for the config file (So I can have docker-compose-local and docker-compose-production)

Everything works fine for local and production, but I am wondering if this is a bad practice? how could I do it a nicer way? is this against docker principles?

If can be done differently, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Dude, if it's remote, just connect to the remote, you don't need any container for it. I'm pretty sure your application does not care where it connects to as long as it works.

Comment: thanks for the comment @emix, for me it doesnt matter either, just wondering if there is an approach for this? or is against any docker rule somehow

Comment: There's no such rule. It's up to you how you connect to a database.

Comment: How do you specify the database location not-in-Docker?  Do the exact same thing.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a different type of labeling for this kind of resources....